# keras neural network architecture incorrect

Tags: neural-network, keras

Here is a simple neural network that contains 3 input values and 3 output values.

The error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_78 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (3, 1)
```

Is thrown when I execute this network. I've the set the final layer to have 3 possible outputs which match the number of labels :

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

I've not architected this network correctly, where is my mistake ?

```
data = ([[ 0.29365378],
       [ 0.27958957],
       [ 0.27946938]])

labels = [[1], [2], [3]]

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dense(3...)` will give you three outputs **per sample**.

The output of a `Dense(3...)` has shape (BatchSize,3), or `(None,3)` as Keras says it.

If you want one among 3 possible classes for each sample, then you must have `labels` with shape (BatchSize,3). Where in your case the batch size also seems to be 3.

You must format your labels in `one-hot` vectors:

- class 1 = [1,0,0]
- class 2 = [0,1,0]
- class 3 = [0,0,1]

The [to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) in keras.utils can help you with transforming numerical classes into one-hot vector classes.

If you have three samples, you must have labels as:

```
labels = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Three samples, each sample with three possible classes, being the first sample class 1, the second sample class 2 and the third sample class 3.

This has shape (3,3) which will match the (None,3) demanded by `Dense(3...)`.